# If statement to hide a <Div>

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement, hide

I'm pulling both the 'book_series' and 'series_link' from custom fields within Wordpress.

The link shows up correctly when a name and URL are included but it shows "Books Series:' on blank pages (that don't include links or series). How can I hide the content when left blank?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php if (('books_series') == true) : ?>
              <div class="series"><b>Book Series: </b><a href="<?php the_field( 'series_link' ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field( 'books_series' ); ?></a></div>
            <?php else: ?>
              <div class="series" hidden></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
if (('books_series') == true)
```

Should be:

```
if (the_field('books_series') == true)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it essentially outputs the field twice. I'm really not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with and it seems to work, although I'm not sure how functional it is overall - `

```
      <?php if ($series_link) { ?>
            <div class="series"><b>Book Series: </b><a href="<?php the_field( 'series_link' ); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field( 'books_series' ); ?></a></div>
      <?php } ?>`
```

Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions.